# Display SSD1306 stops working after a short while on esp32

Tags: arduino, esp32, adafruit

I'm currently working on a sensor box, that displays the sensor data non stop in the loop of a ESP32 Node MCU on a SSD1306 Display, connected over I2C (21 and 22). But then the display does weird stuff.

I can't share all of the ESP32 Code right now, but this should be all the needed stuff anyways I guess:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
    initializeDisplay();
}

void loop() {
    ...
    writeToDisplay(.......);
}

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128     // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64     // OLED display height, in pixels
#define OLED_RESET -1         // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3C 
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);
bool initializeDisplay() {
  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, SCREEN_ADDRESS)) {
    return false;
  }
  display.display();
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.println("Display initialized!");
  display.display();
  display.clearDisplay();
  return true;
}




void writeToDisplay(float colorTemp, float lux, float dbValue, String temperature, String relH, String co2) {
      display.clearDisplay();
      displayText ="";
      displayText += "Lux ";
      displayText += String(lux,1);
      displayText += "lx\n";
    
      displayText += "Color Temp. ";
      displayText += String(colorTemp, 1);
      displayText += "K\n";
    
      displayText += "Noise level: ";
      displayText += String(dbValue, 1);
      displayText += "dbA\n";
    
      displayText += "Temperature: ";
      displayText += temperature;
      displayText += "C\n";
    
      displayText += "relH ";
      displayText += relH;
      displayText += "%\n";
    
      displayText += "CO2 ";
      displayText += co2;
      displayText += "ppm\n";
      if(isPortable()) {
        displayText += "Portable Mode";
      }
      display.println(displayText);
      display.display();
    }
```

In the beginning everything works great, but after a minute or so this happens:
[image]

Is this a memory or flash issue? Does anyone have any idea? I don't think it's a power issue.

Comment: What's the output from ESP's serial console when the problem occurs?

Comment: Program goes on and on and no error in the console. Even some Http Client stuff in the background is still executed. Not sure if there is something when debug is enabled, I will check.

Comment: There is nothing in the console, even with log level 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was, there were too many devices connected over the same I2C bus.
So what fixed this:

- Instead of soldering Display, two Sensors and a real time clock to GPIO 21 and 22, I soldered the display to GPIO 32 and 33.
- Added `Wire1.begin(32, 33);` to setup
- Changed constructor of display to `Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire1, -1);`

I guess the display stops working as soon as there is too much traffic on the bus. So this was not a memory problem